# C - Writing a function for an exponent without using Pow

Tags: c

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int x_to_the_n (int x,int n)
{
    int i; 
    int number;


 int i; 
int i = 1;

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    x = x*x;

return(number);
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    int exponent;
    int answer;

    printf  ("Enter a number: ");
    scanf ("%i", &number);

    printf  ("Enter a number that represents the power you want your number to be raised     to: ");
    scanf ("%i", &exponent);

    answer = x_to_the_n(number,exponent); 

    printf("X To The N is %li",answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Right now, the function x_to_the_n is not correctly equating x ^ n...I was wondering if anyone had suggestions to calculate x to the n without using the c pow library function.

Comment: This is a very basic question. Looking at your code it appears that you haven't invested a slightest effort into it. SO isn't here to solve your hw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
long int x_to_the_n (int x,int n)
{
    int i; /* Variable used in loop counter */
    int number = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        number *= x;

    return(number);
}
```

Comment: This is *not* the way to do integer exponentiation -- you do not need to perform n multiplies -- you can do it with ceil(log2(n))  multiplies. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring