# C- function for printing each base exponent For example, integerPower( 3, 4 ) = 3 * 3 * 3 * 3

Tags: c

I can't seem to get my program running

Write a function integerPower(base, exponent) that
returns the value of
Baseexponent. For example, integerPower( 3, 4 ) = 3 * 3 * 3 * 3. Assume that
exponent is a positive, nonzero
integer, and base is an integer. Function integerPower should use for to
control the calculation.
Do not use any math library functions.

i have this  program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int power(int b, int e){

int x
for (x = 0; x <= e; x++)
    b=b;

return b;
}

void main(){
int b = 0;
int e = 0;

scanf("input a base %d\n", &b);
scanf("input an exponent %d\n", &e);

power(b,e);

printf("%d" , b);

}
```

Comment: `power(b,e);` this statement calculates something and throws away the return value.

Comment: First thing to notice, is the b=b inside the for loop. I think what you want is b *= b

Comment: Start by reading the compiler error messages and fixing them (e.g. missing semicolon after `int x`), so that the code will at least compile. Then you can start debugging...

Comment: don't do `void main(){`

Comment: also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265230/c-writing-a-function-for-an-exponent-without-using-pow?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In the loop

```
for (x = 0; x <= e; x++)
   b=b;
```

the line `b=b;` is useless. It just assign the value of `b` to itself. You need to multiply `b` by `e` times. For this you need to take another variable with initial value `1` and multiply it by `b` at each iteration of loop to get `b`<sup>e</sup>.
Change your function to this

```
int power(int b, int e){
    int x, y = 1;
    for (x = 1; x <= e; x++)
        y = y*b;  // Multiply e times

    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int power(int b, int e){

    int x;
    int result = 1;
    for (x = 0; x < e; x++)
       result*=b;

    return result;
}

int main(){
    int b = 0;
    int e = 0;

    printf("Input a base ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Input an exponent ");
    scanf("%d", &e);

    b = power(b,e);

    printf("%d" , b);
    return 0;
}
```

First problem is with the scanf function. you are using "input a base ". For this to output you have to use printf("input a base ").

Comment: Oh That's by mistake. I just copied the original problem. Corrected the same and other issues with power function.

Comment: Thanks guys it runs. But if I want it to print the base the same as the number of exponents eg.10^4 prints 10*10*10*10

Comment: better, so +1 for the only answer which also handles the error in the `main()` function

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below function to calculate the value of base raised to the power of exponent

```
int ipower(int b, int e)
{
    int x, tmp = 1;

    for (x = 0; x < e; x++)
        tmp *= b;

    return tmp;
}
```

Here the for loop is iterated for e times that is from 0 to e-1. "tmp" will hold the result.
Make sure you don't change the value of "b/e"(base/exponent) inside the loop, else will lead to wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

doing b*=b in function body won't help either. And why initialize b and e to zero when you're supposed to input them from the user?
Try this:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int power(int b, int e) {
    int temp = b;
    int x;
        for (x = 1; x < e; x++)
            b *= temp;

    return b;
}
void main() {
    int b ;
    int e;
    scanf_s(" %d", &b);
    scanf_s(" %d", &e);

   int h= power(b, e);

    printf("%d", h);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int power(int b, int e){

int x,t=1
for (x = 1; x <= e; x++)
    t*=b;

return t;
}
```

if user give e= 1 then also its work.